# What is "->" operator called and purpose does it serve?

Tags: c

I'm looking at C-based Solana Smart Contracts and I see `->` operator in the code.  How do I search for this as I don't even know what to call it (I have tried with no results)?

```
/**
 * @brief C-based Helloworld BPF program
 */
#include <solana_sdk.h>

uint64_t helloworld(SolParameters *params) {

  if (params->ka_num < 1) {
    sol_log("Greeted account not included in the instruction");
    return ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_ACCOUNT_KEYS;
  }

  // Get the account to say hello to
  SolAccountInfo *greeted_account = &params->ka[0];

}
```

Comment: Read any beginner's book on C.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know "what" to look for.  Answer can be found on p203 of The C Programming Language by Kernigan & Ritchie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `->` operator is related to the `.` operator.

The `.` operator expects a variable with `struct` or `union` type on the left and the name of a member of that `struct` or `union` on the right.

The `->` does the same thing, except that the left operand is a *pointer* to a `struct` or `union`.

That means that this:

```
params->ka_num
```

Is an equivalent and cleaner way of writing this:

```
(*params).ka_num
```

Comment: Especially if you need to chain them.  `foo->bar->baz` vs. `(*(*foo).bar).baz`

Answer (score 1):

It must be a pointer dereference operator `->`.